# Jquery: Parent div not selected for fadein

Tags: jquery, parent, fade

I have a mouseover function but when I try to fade in the `optionbox`, it does it to all the classes named 'box'. I have tried to set `this` in there but my jquery-skills (if I have some already) are letting me down.

Aside from this problem the code is working fine.

```
   $(".box").live({
    mouseenter:
       function()
       {
        optionsTimeout = setTimeout(

            function() {
                $('.optionbox').fadeIn(200);
            }

        , 1000);
       },
    mouseleave:
       function()
       {
        clearTimeout(optionsTimeout);
        $('.optionbox').fadeOut(200);
       }
   }
);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="optionbox"><a href="">Delete</a></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="optionbox"><a href="">Delete</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A sample of the HTML would be good - otherwise we don't know what you need to target.  Oh, FYI, you should use .on() instead of live if you're using jQuery 1.7 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mouseenter: function() {
    (function (self) {
        var optionsTimeout = setTimeout(function() { 
            $('.optionbox', self).fadeIn(200); 
        }, 1000);
        self.data('showTimeout', optionsTimeout);
    })($(this)); 
},
mouseleave: function () {
   var self = $(this),
       optionsTimeout = self.data('showTimeout');
   clearTimeout(optionsTimeout);
   $('.optionbox', this).fadeOut(200);
}
```

You need to tell jQuery to use elements within the contextual `.box`, therefore the use of `$(selector, context)`.

The enclosing function with self is to save a reference to the context inside the execution of the timeout, so you pass it as a parameter of a self-executable function, and when the timeout expires it will have a reference to the executing `.box`

You could also encounter problems by using the same global variable for all timeouts, so you shoul save the contextual timeout code for each one, in my example I use `$.data` to save the code, and restore it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".box").live({
    mouseenter: function() {
       var $that = $(this);
       optionsTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
           $that.find('.optionbox').fadeIn(200);
       }, 1000);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        clearTimeout(optionsTimeout);
        $(this).find('.optionbox').fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` (the `.box` element) inside the handler as a context:

```
$(this).find('.optionbox').fadeIn(200);
```

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `$(this).find('.optionbox')` to only get elements within the current element.